# Gmail - link in email causing extra reload on target website

Tags: php, symfony, email, gmail

I've got a simple registration process implemented on my website - user enters email in registration form and system sends on that email confirmation link with some random hash to complete checkout. Link looks like this:

```
http://somedomain.com/registration_confirm/1/be770f0a002f181deedcb3d8da2f9f638579ace3fe218251fe3558824ba548d2
```

also, in email template:

```
<a href="{{ url('registration_confirm', { '_locale': app.request.locale, 'readerId': readerId, 'registrationDigest': registrationDigest }) }}">
    {{ 'registration.link'|trans({}, "emails") }}
</a>
```

When it's got delivered on **Gmail**, and I click that link - something strange happens: target page is loaded twice. So I get to the `registration_confirm` route, and than browser loads `registration_confirm` route again. Which is problem, because on second load link is not valid anymore, and user sees an error.

**Symfony2** is the framework, and my route definition looks like this:

```
/**
 * @Method({"GET"})
 * @Route(
 *      "/registration_confirm/{readerId}/{registrationDigest}",
 *      name="registration_confirm",
 *      host="{domain}",
 *      defaults={"_locale" = "%locale%", "domain" = "%domain%"},
 *      requirements={"_locale" = "%locale%", "domain" = "%domain%", "readerId" = "\d+", "registrationDigest" = "[a-f0-9]{64}"}
 * )
 */
```

Checked across different browsers - same result. Checked with different email services - *all except Gmail works as expected*, so I assume that Gmail itself does something unwanted.

Appreciate any thoughts about this issue, because for now it looks like voodoo magic.

Comment: Does the same happen when you open it in a new tab/window?

Comment: @Kid Binary Can you update the anchor tag also? The code you add in the mail.

Comment: @user2268997: well, when I just copy that link and open it in a new tab, everything's fine. So only following link from Gmail causes trouble.